# How to get center of an MKMapView map?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I have an MKMapView which allows the user to scroll the map around. Later, I want to get the latitude and longitude of the point at the center of the map, but can't find an easy way to do it. At the moment I'm trying something like:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centre = [locationMap convertPoint:locationMap.center toCoordinateFromView:locationMap];
txtLatitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",centre.latitude];
txtLongitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",centre.longitude];
```

But it's not working - both latitude and longitude both come out as zero. I'd be grateful for any ideas anyone might have!

==============

## -- Update 1 --

Oh. If I add the:

```
NSLog(@"%@", locationMap);
```

line as suggested below, the log shows "(null)". I've got the following in my header (amongst other things):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

IBOutlet MKMapView *locationMap;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *locationMap;
```

and the following in my methods file:

```
@synthesize locationMap;
```

This is compiling without any warnings or errors at present. Starting to wonder if I've missed something obvious?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

What about the [centerCoordinate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW48) property?

i.e.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centre = [locationMap centerCoordinate];
```

If the `centerCoordindate` property is all 0, check that you've got a valid locationMap pointer - objective-c will let you send messages to nil without any errors!

Try `NSLog(@"%@", locationMap);` - if that outputs nil, you've probably forgotten to connect the mapLocation to a MKMapView in Interface Builder ;)

Comment: Is locationMap a valid pointer - what does __NSLog(@"%@", locationMap);__ say?

Comment: Have you connected your locationMap in interface builder - it won't automatically know that you want the map in your xib to be connected to the locationMap property!

Comment: I had indeed completely forgotten to do that! Told you it would be something obvious - thanks!